# Visual Studio images not displaying

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am having a program written and I am developing on 2 different pcs.

First PC: Windows 7 Professional 64bit with VS 2015 Community.

Second PC: Windows 10 64bit with VS 2013.

Problem:

On the first PC, when I build and run the program or even just run the exe, the icons for the buttons are not displaying. It shows only square boxes in place of icons. I am getting no errors either. Everything works fine on the second PC.

Any idea why this may be? I have googled and cannot seem to find an answer.

Comment: Can you show us how are you setting the images ? If you're using local paths `C:/ ...` so it is common sense that is it not gonna work because that image is not found on the second PC. You need to append your images to the project as project resources.

Comment: The image path is set to call to images in the folder where the program is installed. I understand what you are saying though.

Comment: Does you image show in the solution explorer ? If so, you need to go to its properties and set it Copy Settings to Content. If you copy and paste an image to your solutions folder, it doesn't mean the image is part of your solution when you move your exe you publish using ClickOnce. The best approach is go to your project settings > resources and add the image there. And then use it inside your code using `Properties.Resources.YouImageName;`

Answer (score 5):

If you just copy and paste the images into the folder of your project using windows, it is unlikely that the build is gonna predict that you need this image as a part of your process.

You need to add an image item to your project using Visual Studio and set its properties (`Copy To Ouput Directory => Always`).

Or the best approach is go to your Project Settings > Resources and add an image resource from existing file there. And then use it inside your code using `Properties.Resources.YouImageName` you through the designer.